# Running java application with MongoDB database in Kubernetes - on prem

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a java application that writes data to MnogoDB database which so far I run it in a monolithic approach for Production.

We consider moving it to Kubernetes cluster:
the data should not be lost and should be persistent.

should we deploy the MongoDB inside the Kubernetes cluster as a pod with persistent volume pod? is it safe ? what happens if the cluster is crushed?
Or should I deploy only the Java application to the cluster and the database will be outside of the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is a stateless container orchestrator by its nature ( meaning it is not designed for databases by intension )   ,  later it was extended and adapted for databases with the statefullset API and you can customize and adapt it for mongoDB , but the statefull deployments become alot complex and difficult to support and mantain so it become alot easier to use k8s operator for the task.

The choices are:

**1) Keep your database outside k8s.**

pros:

- easier and simple
- you dont need k8s for scaling and redundancy in  mongoDB database , mongoDB support internally horizontal scaling via sharding and redundancy via replication
- keep the persistency layer outside k8s make the k8s apps maintenace alot simpler

cons:

- you will need to take care yourself about upgrades/maintenance/monitoring for something that is outside k8s

**2) Go to ATLAS(mongoDB SaaS).**

pros:

- mongoDB support it for you , so you dont have to do too much by yourself.

cons:

- could be expensive when your data size and usage grow.

**3) Use mongoDB k8s enterprise operator.**

pros:

- It supports sharded cluster and it use ops manager to deploy and re-configure sharded cluster components.

cons:

- there is a price.

**4) Use mongoDB k8s community operator.**

pros:

- free

cons:

- It is limited to replicaSet ( In general means that if your database grow above certain size you will not be able to split and distribute to shards)

**5) Use 3th party community operator.**

pros:

- there is some options out there , bitnami , percona etc.

cons:

- there is learning curve to understand 3th party company intentions.

**6) Deploy via custom statefulset helm chart.**

pros:

- you can customize as per your needs

cons:

- complex and will require alot of effort to mitigate the default k8s native behaviour

I will not sound very modern if I say keep it outside k8s for reliability , but this is my choice , if you need to be modern it is best to use the SaaS provided by the vendor(mongoDB ATLAS) ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use MongoDB Atlas for Database Deployments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).